# how can write the sql query for the following records

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table - fu_plan_user (id_plan_user,id_user, id_plan, valid_from, valid_to, ...)
table - fu_user (id_user, name, company....)
table - fu_plan (id_plan, name, duration, ...)
```

I want to produce a list of accounts that have a close(valid_to) date which is the end of a month and this date should be in the future, like grater than todays date (NOW()). The name should not contain "trial" word.

The list should include:

```
id_user
payplan name (fu_plan->name)
customer name (fu_user->name)
end date (fu_plan_user->valid_to)
```

I have tried this so far but no success

```
SELECT * 
from fu_plan_user 
where da_valid_to > now() 
  and da_valid_to > DATEADD(day, 30, GETDATE());
```

How can i produce this list of records with MySQL query?

Comment: It's quite clear you want valid_to later than now, but not clear what the other condition is

Comment: How is "the end of a month" defined?

Comment: Sample data and desired results, please.

Comment: end of month is 30th (day >= 30)

Comment: something like this                                                                           SELECT user.id_user, payplan.name, planUser.company, planUser.valid_to from fu_plan_user planUser, fu_user user, fu_plan payplan where planUser.da_valid_to > now() and planUser.da_valid_to >= DATEADD(d, 30, getdate())